# Intellij, How to set JVM parameters for Junit Unit Tests?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, ide

I have changed JVM options by Run/Debug Configurations(`-Xms512m`), but when I run testcase, IntellijIdea call use below args, replication option `-Xms`:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:58896,suspend=y,server=n **-Xms512m -Xms256m** -Xmx512m -
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the run configuration - click on the drop-down next to run run icon on the menu bar, and select "Edit Configurations..." then select the tests and enter any JVM options you require.

Comment: Worked just fine for me.